# i3WM unable to start insync and Dropbox

Tags: window-manager, i3, dropbox

I have the following commands in my i3wm config file:

```
exec --no-startup-id 'workspace $ws10; exec insync start; exec insync show'
exec --no-startup-id 'workspace $ws10; exec dropbox start'
```

I don't get any error when I compile the i3wm config file. But at the start, none of the two clients are run. I have to do that manually from the terminal. Then they show up and minimize to the tray.

When I try to set up a keybinding for the same like this:

```
bindsym $mod+i 'exec insync start; exec insync show'
```

I get an error as show in this image:
[image: Error image]

What am I doing wrong here? How to make the two clients run at startup. Any inputs would be very helpful.

I have also tried the following command with nothing to avail:

```
exec --no-startup-id 'exec insync start && insync show'
exec --no-startup-id 'exec dropbox start'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without the quotes and the extra exec, for example
`exec --no-startup-id dropbox start`
should do. But note that current insync may need an extra sleep so that it is launched only when the status bar/systray is ready.